# React Native Arabic (RTL) without forceRTL

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In RN my bilingual app (English - Arabic), I have used `I18nManager` (views) and `I18n` (for translations)

When I am changing app language to Arabic, the whole app gets reloaded again from the splash-screen using this code:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
```

Ideally, it should not restart the app from start and it should continue with the current screen with Arabic data.

Currently, it is not happening, only translation elements are getting converted using `I18n.t('keyword')` but for views Arabic alignment, it's not proper.

Still looking for a better solution, let me know if anyone achieved it.

Thanks
Sopo !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put this code in the top component in your project

```
import RNRestart from "react-native-restart";
```

`I18nManager.forceRTL(true);`
`if (!I18nManager.isRTL) RNRestart.Restart();`

Comment: its causing app reload, I want to keep it without reloading bro.

Comment: I think its impossible changing direction without reloading the app

Answer (score 1):

If you guys wants to **store stack state** after reloading(because there is no other option without reloading) and want stack state back you can follow this link also you can check my code.
Link: [React navigation state persist](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/)

**Any Component**

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('navigation_state', JSON.stringify(navigation.dangerouslyGetState()));
```

**My App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    restoreState();
  }, []);
  const restoreState = async () => {
    try {
      const savedStateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('navigation_state');
      const state = savedStateString ? JSON.parse(savedStateString) : undefined;
      if (state !== undefined) {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('navigation_state');
        setInitialState(state);
      }
    } finally {
      setIsReady(true);
    }
  };
  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer
        initialState={initialState}
        ref={rootNavigationRef}>
        <Root>
          <AppNavigator />
        </Root>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I working on a project which has two languages, Arabic and English.i use redux for handling app language. I put all styles on redux and handle app style with redux. and when user change language all styles on my app change to that language . also all text handled with redux too. with this way, my app does not reload and app language changed immediately.

Comment: So there is no other simple option ?, it will cause me huge amount of efforts to change app code for moving onto redux

Comment: yes, it's a huge change, but I just share my experience, maybe give an idea from it

Answer (score 0):

If your app is an android hybrid app, you can try this:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

I18nUtil i18nUtil = I18nUtil.getInstance();
i18nUtil.forceRTL(context, forceRtl);
i18nUtil.allowRTL(context, true);
```

value 'forceRtl' is a boolean.

for iOS,I think you can find the same method.

Answer (score -1):

In Expo use

```js
import {Updates} from "expo"

Updates.reload()
```